# Search outside of hidden sequences, but get original line numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have file containing list of lines like this:

```
-apple
banana tomato
-orange
maracuja
cucumber <hide>
peanut
-apple
apricot
grapefruit </hide> banana
lime
-grape
lemon
```

I want to find all `-` prefixed lines and write them to the dict as follows: `{original_line_number: '-apple', ...}`, but exclude the ones in `<hide></hide>` segment. It seems pretty easy, but in my real usecase I have got multiple and really complicated `<hide>` sequences. For each I've prepared complicated regex pattern in re.compile like this:

```
re.compile(r'really complicated regex for 1st hide sequence (' + r'|'.join(some_list_of_possibilities) + r') yeah it still continue%s' % not_enough_complicated_yet)
```

**Is there a way to get list of lines with `-` prefix, exclude the ones in hidden sequences and still index their original line numbers?**

What I've already tried:

1. Remove hidden sequences, get `-` prefixed lines, compare with original list and get line numbers: Fails if there is one `-` prefixed line inside and the same line outside of hide sequence as in example is `-apple`
2. Replace all characters in hide sequences by spaces except `\n` chars: Fails to me because I can not find out how to keep `\n` characters (not to replace them by spaces)

Note: I want to get `-` prefixed lines "as is", therefore if there is line like `-apple <hide> banana`, I want to get the whole line content :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by replacing all chars in hidden sequences by spaces (or any other substitute character) - but except newlines. This keeps line numbers and disables hidden sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()


res = []
skip = False
for index, x in enumerate(content):
    val = x.strip()
    if skip:
        if '</hide>' in val:
            skip = False

    if '<hide>' in val:
        skip = True

    if not skip:
        if val.startswith('-'):
            res.append({index+1: val})

print res

[{1: '-apple'}, {3: '-orange'}, {11: '-grape'}]
```

Comment: As I've said, I have got multiple hide sequences to search for like `<hide>`, `{{hide}}`, `<{ commented part is here watch:\n-apple\nbanana\n:commented part ends here}>` and so, so this solution would be too complicated